# Объединение меток [singleton] и [шаблон-одиночка]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие метки:

- [singleton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton)
- [шаблон-одиночка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0) с синонимом [pattern-singleton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pattern-singleton)

Может быть [singleton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) надо тоже синонимизировать с [шаблон-одиночка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0)?

Comment: Синонимизировать надо, но у меток уже есть отдельное описание. Поэтому надо сначала создать какое-то общее наиболее полное описание, а потом синонимизировать.

Answer (score 2):

Описание у меток практически совпадает (чует мой нос, что оно скопировано из википедии).
 Думаю, что стоит синомизиро.... синонимози.... Короче, объединить метки в сторону [singleton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton), потому что:

- С этой меткой больше вопросов.
- Скорее всего, искать вопросы и ответы будут тоже по ней, ведь в вопросах с [шаблон-одиночка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0) используется термин `singelton`.

---

Лучше всего, попросить синонимизи.... синоминизи... (ну вы поняли) модератора, ибо только модератор может сделать это единолично, в пару кликов (конечно, можно и без модератора, но это долго). И кстати, только модератор может повесить [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

Comment: Не важно какую метку из си-но-ни-ми-зи-ро-ван-ных использовать при поиске. Любая из них даст одинаковый результат. Для того оно и си-но-ни-мы.